# is this a good bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I haven't ridden a bike in many years. I am looking at this Trek bike, but I'm not sure on the model so I can't look up any info on it. Can anyone identify it for me please? And also, let me know if it's a good bike to start off with? The guy said it's in excellent condition, and ready to ride. 
[image: unknown trek]

Comment: Any bike beats walking!   You should test-ride it first to make sure its comfortable and a good fit.

Comment: It's your basic bike, though one that's a step up (maybe two) from "department store" bikes.  If in good condition it should be a fine "starter" bike, but if it suits you well you could end up using it for a long time.  It does appear to be 15-20 years old, so the tires may be rotting, and if it was left exposed to the weather at all it could have some rust issues in the cables.  (Hint:  Inspect the chain.  If it's rusty then the bike has not been well cared for.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a women's Trek bicycle, i can't read it from the image but the model is more than likely one of those teal words on the frame. Google Trek and then those words and look for an image that looks the same.

More than likely basic components but if the price is right and you like it a bike is a bike. If there is rust on the chain or crankset it is not in "excellent ready to ride" condition for someone who does not know how to service it.

Trek is a reputable brand but that appears to be a low level model, not that there is anything wrong with that. There should be a serial number on it, possibly the bottom of the frame by the crank, that may also lead you to find the model and year if you then search that serial number.